# Debugging HTML/JavaScript code for OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, html

I'm really stumped on why my HTML/Javascript code isn't working. My webpage currently only shows my map div, but no actual map content.

My code so far:

HTML:

```
 <style type="text/css">

 #mymap {
 width: 650px;
 height: 550px;
 border: thin dashed;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }

  h2 {
 text-align: center;
 }

 </style>

<body onload="initMap();">

<div id="container">

 <br>
 <div id="mymap">
 </div>
  <div id="legend"></div>
 </div>

Javascript:
var map;

function initMap() {
 //initialise variables
 var osmlayer;
 var google_terrain;
 var point;

 //create new map object
 map = new OpenLayers.Map("mymap");


 //create new API layers
 osmlayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Open Street Map");
 google_terrain = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Terrain Map", {
     type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
     numZoomLevels; 22
 });     

//add layers to the map
 map.addLayer([osmlayer, google_terrain]);

 map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());


 // define point as a new LonLat object and transfom
 point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-6.67, 55.15);
 point.transform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:900913");

 //center the map and set zoom level
 map.setCenter(point,10);

 }
```

Comment: What version of openlayers do you use? Syntax looks like and old openLayers 2, which has different syntax than OL3/4. If you use OL2 do you have reason for that? It is no longer supported or in development.

Answer (score 2):

Below a solution. You will need to replace YOUR_API_KEY with your own Google Maps API key. Now, this key is mandatory. Be careful it costs (see [this article](http://geoawesomeness.com/developers-up-in-arms-over-google-maps-api-insane-price-hike/))

The issues in our code were

- `numZoomLevels; 22` (should be `numZoomLevels: 22`)
- `map.addLayer([osmlayer, google_terrain]);` (should be `map.addLayers([osmlayer, google_terrain]);`)

The full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
    #mymap {
    width: 650px;
    height: 550px;
    border: thin dashed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    h2 {
    text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
    <script src="http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function initMap() {
    //initialise variables
    var osmlayer;
    var google_terrain;
    var point;
    //create new map object
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("mymap");
    //create new API layers
    osmlayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Open Street Map");
    google_terrain = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Terrain Map", {
    type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    numZoomLevels: 22
    });
    //add layers to the map
    map.addLayers([osmlayer, google_terrain]);
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
    // define point as a new LonLat object and transfom
    point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-6.67, 55.15);
    point.transform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:900913");
    //center the map and set zoom level
    map.setCenter(point,10);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initMap();">
    <div id="container">
      <br>
      <div id="mymap">
      </div>
      <div id="legend"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```